# Необходимо сделать так, что бы в нечетных новостях картинка была слева, а в четных справа

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс

Есть компонент битрикс bitrix:news и bitrix:news.list, надо сделать так, что бы в каждой нечетной новости картинка была слева, а в каждой четной-справа, код компонентов прилагаю:
bitrix:news

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>

<?if($arParams["USE_RSS"]=="Y"):?>
    <?
    if(method_exists($APPLICATION, 'addheadstring'))
        $APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="'.$arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["rss"].'" href="'.$arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["rss"].'" />');
    ?>
    <a href="<?=$arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["rss"]?>" title="rss" target="_self"><img alt="RSS" src="<?=$templateFolder?>/images/gif-light/feed-icon-16x16.gif" border="0" align="right" /></a>
<?endif?>

<?if($arParams["USE_SEARCH"]=="Y"):?>
<?=GetMessage("SEARCH_LABEL")?><?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:search.form",
    "flat",
    Array(
        "PAGE" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["search"]
    ),
    $component
);?>
<br />
<?endif?>
<?if($arParams["USE_FILTER"]=="Y"):?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.filter",
    "",
    Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "FILTER_NAME" => $arParams["FILTER_NAME"],
        "FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["FILTER_FIELD_CODE"],
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["FILTER_PROPERTY_CODE"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => $arParams["PAGER_PARAMS_NAME"],
    ),
    $component
);
?>
<br />
<?endif?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "",
    Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "NEWS_COUNT" => $arParams["NEWS_COUNT"],
        "SORT_BY1" => $arParams["SORT_BY1"],
        "SORT_ORDER1" => $arParams["SORT_ORDER1"],
        "SORT_BY2" => $arParams["SORT_BY2"],
        "SORT_ORDER2" => $arParams["SORT_ORDER2"],
        "FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_FIELD_CODE"],
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_PROPERTY_CODE"],
        "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
        "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
        "IBLOCK_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"],
        "DISPLAY_PANEL" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PANEL"],
        "SET_TITLE" => $arParams["SET_TITLE"],
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => $arParams["SET_LAST_MODIFIED"],
        "MESSAGE_404" => $arParams["MESSAGE_404"],
        "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
        "SHOW_404" => $arParams["SHOW_404"],
        "FILE_404" => $arParams["FILE_404"],
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => $arParams["INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"],
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"],
        "PAGER_TITLE" => $arParams["PAGER_TITLE"],
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["PAGER_TEMPLATE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALL"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK"],
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => $arParams["PAGER_PARAMS_NAME"],
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"],
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"],
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"],
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => $arParams["PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN"],
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => $arParams["LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT"],
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["USE_PERMISSIONS"],
        "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["GROUP_PERMISSIONS"],
        "FILTER_NAME" => $arParams["FILTER_NAME"],
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => $arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"],
        "CHECK_DATES" => $arParams["CHECK_DATES"],
    ),
    $component
);?>
```

bitrix:news.list

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<div class="news-list">
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
    <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br />
<?endif;?>
<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
    <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
    <p class="news-item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
            <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><img
                        class="preview_picture"
                        border="0"
                        src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                        width="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                        height="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                        alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                        title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                        style="float:left"
                        /></a>
            <?else:?>
                <img
                    class="preview_picture"
                    border="0"
                    src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                    width="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                    height="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                    alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                    title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                    style="float:left"
                    />
            <?endif;?>
        <?endif?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"]!="N" && $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]):?>
            <span class="news-date-time"><?echo $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?></span>
        <?endif?>
         <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_NAME"]!="N" && $arItem["NAME"]):?>
            <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                <a href="<?echo $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><b><?echo $arItem["NAME"]?></b></a><br />
            <?else:?>
                 <b><?echo $arItem["NAME"]?></b><br />
            <?endif;?>
        <?endif;?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"]!="N" && $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"]):?>
            <?echo $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"];?>
        <?endif;?> 

        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <?endif?>
        <?foreach($arItem["FIELDS"] as $code=>$value):?>
            <small>
            <?=GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_".$code)?>:&nbsp;<?=$value;?>
            </small><br />
        <?endforeach;?>
        <?foreach($arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>
            <small>
            <?=$arProperty["NAME"]?>:&nbsp;
            <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?>
                <?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?>
            <?else:?>
                <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
            <?endif?>
            </small><br />
        <?endforeach;?>
    </p>
<?endforeach;?>
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
    <br /><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
<?endif;?>

</div>
```

Comment: деление с остатком 2 % 2 == 0 значит четное, либо css.

Answer (score 0):

Странный у Вас шаблон конечно, нет разделения на блоки, подобие колонок, надеюсь простое перемещение Вам поможет. Хотя возможно Вам придётся будет добавлять классы для уникализации где картинка расположена и дописывать css.
Для решения Вам необходимо перед циклом создать переменную, в которой Вы будете считать какой это номер новости внутри цикла, и проверять чётный номер или нечётный путём деления с остатком (($i % 2) == 0). При таком делении на 2, если возвращается 0, то число чётное, если 1, то число нечётное. bitrix:news.list

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<div class="news-list">
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
    <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br />
<?endif;?>
<? $i = 1; ?>
<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
    <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
    <p class="news-item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
        <? if(($i % 2) != 0){ ?>
            <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
                <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                    <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">
                        <img
                            class="preview_picture"
                            border="0"
                            src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                            width="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                            height="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                            alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                            title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                            style="float:left"
                            />
                    </a>
                <?else:?>
                    <img
                        class="preview_picture"
                        border="0"
                        src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                        width="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                        height="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                        alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                        title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                        style="float:left"
                        />
                <?endif;?>
            <?endif;?>
        <? } ?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"]!="N" && $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]):?>
            <span class="news-date-time"><?echo $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?></span>
        <?endif?>
         <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_NAME"]!="N" && $arItem["NAME"]):?>
            <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                <a href="<?echo $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><b><?echo $arItem["NAME"]?></b></a><br />
            <?else:?>
                 <b><?echo $arItem["NAME"]?></b><br />
            <?endif;?>
        <?endif;?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"]!="N" && $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"]):?>
            <?echo $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"];?>
        <?endif;?> 

        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <?endif?>
        <?foreach($arItem["FIELDS"] as $code=>$value):?>
            <small>
            <?=GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_".$code)?>:&nbsp;<?=$value;?>
            </small><br />
        <?endforeach;?>
        <?foreach($arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>
            <small>
            <?=$arProperty["NAME"]?>:&nbsp;
            <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?>
                <?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?>
            <?else:?>
                <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
            <?endif?>
            </small><br />
        <?endforeach;?>
        <? if(($i % 2) == 0){ ?>
            <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
                <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                    <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">
                        <img
                            class="preview_picture"
                            border="0"
                            src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                            width="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                            height="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                            alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                            title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                            style="float:left"
                            />
                    </a>
                <?else:?>
                    <img
                        class="preview_picture"
                        border="0"
                        src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                        width="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                        height="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                        alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                        title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                        style="float:left"
                        />
                <?endif;?>
            <?endif;?>
        <? } ?>
    </p>
    <? $i++; ?>
<?endforeach;?>
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
    <br /><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
<?endif;?>

</div>
```

Comment: ваш код почему то не работает, причина мне неизвестна, все блоки нововстей едут друг под друга, образуя "лесенку"

Comment: Ерунда какая-то, я просто скопировал Ваш код, все теги закрыты. Попробуйте так, я немного подредактировал

Comment: всё равно лесенка

Comment: У Вас в первую очередь ошибка в вёрстке, нельзя внутри тега <p> использовать теги <br>, <img>, <div>. Тег <p> предназначен под текст. Вам необходимо в первую очередь переделать вёрстку и оборачивать тегом <div>.